# Programmatically Settling a request by Amazon's REST API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rest

I am (developer) using amazon marketplace payment for transaction. For this i am using marketplace fee enabled button (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimplePay/latest/ASPGettingStartedGuide/nomktplc.html).

I want charge a sender's card at a later point so I am using settle (advance feature of amazon marketplace fee enabled button). To settle the transaction I am trying to use this (found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSMarketplaceGuide/Settle.html)

" https://fps.sandbox.amazonaws.com?Action=Settle&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&ReserveTransactionId=14GKD9GE66FAA63E6O6B2JDPZKN53LZ7F22&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Signature=SJJLsIBghi7VIycBjX7c3hnfgZ%2FBvZbzqLtAZXDL8ys%3D&Timestamp=2009-10-06T07%3A53%3A11.750Z&TransactionAmount.CurrencyCode=USD&TransactionAmount.Value=1&Version=2008-09-17 "

My question regarding this request is

1. How should I use it.
2. From where should I call this - the browser or as a normal api call.
3. If it is done by api then what steps should I follow?
4. I made this call directly from the browser but it is always showing
   'SignatureDoesNotMatch' error.

Please suggest what i should do? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Simple Pay solution you are using gives you a very simple HTML integration. The browser does the magic here.

The Amazon Flexible Payment System (FPS) however is an API which is designed to be used by server side code (even though it could be used by JavaScript). You will have to create and properly sign requests to automate this integration. This is considerably more complex than just putting an ASP snippet into your page. I suggest you start here:

- [What Is Amazon FPS](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Amazon-Flexible-Payments-Service/Creating-Managing-Your-Account/What-Is-Amazon-FPS) <- good starting point
- [FPS Sandbox](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Amazon-Flexible-Payments-Service/Technical-Resources/Amazon-FPS-Sandbox) <-- a browser playground for FTP calls